# Does c++ allow function call outside any funtion?

Tags: c++, linux

I have code

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void *gg = malloc(55);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        return 0;
}
```

gcc fail to compile but g++ works.

So, I just want to make sure that the malloc calling happens before main is exectued.

Comment: Fo C, no. For C++, yes. - https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/03/08/non-constant-global-initialization-in-c-and-c

Comment: Yes it legal C++ but not legal C.

Comment: C does not have dynamic initialization stage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you do is allowed in C++. The C++ standard has a whole section on ["Dynamic initialization of non-local variables"](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.start.dynamic).

Looking at the assembly [generated by GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/zvD9ZP) for your code is instructive:

Here the initializers are called through two generated functions, `_GLOBAL__sub_I_gg` (which is called before `main`) which in turn calls `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0`.

It is within the body of the latter function you will find the call to `malloc`.